# Django - Sum annotation adding group by id to clause

Tags: django, postgresql

The following queryset

```
subquery = aggregate_table.objects.filter(
    item__parent__name=OuterRef(dimension)
).annotate(
    aggregate_value=Sum(aggregation_field)
).order_by(
    'item__parent__name'
).values('aggregate_value')

queryset = queryset.annotate(aggregate_value=Subquery(subquery))
```

produces SQL that groups by both the name (supplied by the order_by) and by the id.

```
SELECT SUM(U0."data") AS "aggregate_value"
FROM "aggregate_table" U0
INNER JOIN "item" U1 ON (U0."item_id" = U1."id")
INNER JOIN "parent" U2 ON (U1."parent_id" = U2."id")
WHERE U2."name" = (T12."name")
GROUP BY U0."id",
            U2."name"
ORDER BY U2."name" ASC
```

the ID produces incorrect results and instead of summing and returning 1 row with say 100 as the sum'd value, it returns 100 rows with 1 as the sum'd value.

any ideas on how to remove the u0.id from the group by clause?

**edit:**

Models

```
class aggregate_table(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    item_id = models.ForeignKey(Item, blank=False)
    data = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)

class item(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, blank=False, related_name='parent')

class Parent(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

The goal here is to get the sum of data by parent name. Ideally if I were to write this purely in sql I'd write something like this

```
select sum(data) from aggregate_table
join item on item.id = aggregate_table.item_id
join parent on parent.id = item.parent_id
where xxx
group by parent.name
```

Comment: You can not `ORER BY U2.name`, since that is part of the aggregate, it will thus prevent you from aggregating `SUM(U0.data)` effectively, since for each `U0` there is at least one `U2.name`.

Comment: Perhaps it is better to share your models and ask *what* you want, not *how* you want to achieve this.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I updated to include models and ideally the sql that I'd like to generate (to show what the return set should be). This needs to be as a subquery so that it can fix as an annotation into a much larger query.

Comment: The goal of the order by u2.name was to add it to the group by, which from what I'm reading in Django is (aside from .values_list()) the only way to add it to the group by clause

Answer (score 0):

You can [**`.filter(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) with:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

Parent.objects.annotate(total=Sum('parent__aggregate_table__data'))
```

One can use double underscores (`__`) to look "*through*" relations.
The `Parent`s that arise from this queryset will have an extra attribute `.total` that is the sum of the related `data` of the `aggregate_table`s that have a related item that is related to that `Parent`.

Comment: That does not produce the results needed. The query needs to begin with the aggregate_table to filter results only from the outer query (using OuterRef), and then find the related parents.

Comment: @Mcscrag: but that does not make sense, you perform a `GROUP BY` on the `parent.name`, so that means you query is tailored towarts the `parent` model: you want to obtain the sum *per parent*, otherwise the `GROUP BY` would not make any sense.

Comment: @Mcscrag: if you do not want `Parent`s that have no related `aggregate_table`, that can be filtered out.

Comment: @Mcscrag: but I think that this question "suffers" from the *XY-problem*: you want to achieve *X*, and you assume that you need *Y* for that problem, so you ask how to achieve *Y*, but there are better ways to solve *X* than with *Y*. In other words, I think you should explain what the underlying problem is.